# Binary Tree containsValue method loops endless after return

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, equals

I have a Binary Tree and a working addValue() method. I want to check if the Tree contains an Integer Value starting with the root.
Now I have tried multiple pieces of code, from while loop to recursion. The output is really weird to me.

```
public Boolean containsValue(Integer value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    if (value == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value ist NULL :(");
    }
    return root != null && contains(root, value);

}
private boolean contains(Node node, Integer value) {
    System.out.println(node.getValue());

    Node tempNode = root;
    while (true) {
        if (value.equals(tempNode.getValue())){
            return true;
        }

        if (value.compareTo(tempNode.getValue()) < 0) {
            if (tempNode.getLeft() == null) {
                return false;
            } else
                tempNode = tempNode.getLeft();
        } else {
            if (tempNode.getRight() == null) {
                return false;
            } else
                tempNode = tempNode.getRight();
        }
    }
}
```

My Testclass creates a Tree:

```
private void testContainsSimple(Tree tree) {
    tree.clear();

    tree.addValue(1);
    tree.addValue(7);
    tree.addValue(6);
    tree.addValue(26);
    tree.addValue(11);
    tree.addValue(2);
    tree.addValue(20);
    tree.addValue(12);
    tree.addValue(3);

    Assert.assertEquals(true, tree.containsValue(20));
    Assert.assertEquals(true, tree.containsValue(3));
    Assert.assertEquals(false, tree.containsValue(4));
    Assert.assertEquals(false, tree.containsValue(22));
}
```

The test runs endlessly and produces Output like this:

1
7
6
2
3
26
11
20
1
7
6
2
3
1
7
6
2
3
26
11
20
12
1
7
6
2
3
26
11
20
12
-342450606
-342450606
-1945094521
-1947498669
-1955603908
-2006690011
-2104529452
-2112214429
-2142578581
-2145673805
-2146602265
-2147111222
-2147367018 ....

Why does it happen? I have used a non recursive method but it does the same thing for me.

```
public boolean addValue(Integer value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    // Hinweis: Löschen Sie die folgende Code-Zeile und implementieren Sie
    // die AVL-Einfüge-Operation. Sie können auf die Variable root von
    // AbstractSortedTreeImpl zugreifen, um die Knoten des Baumes
    // entsprechend anzupassen. Die Methode addValue der
    // AbstractSortedTreeImpl kann Ihnen helfen, den Umgang mit der Variable
    // root besser zu verstehen.
    if (value == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value ist NULL");
    }

    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(value);
        return true;
    }

    Node actNode = root;

    boolean posFound = false;
    while (!posFound) {
        if (value.equals(actNode.getValue()))
            return false;

        if (value.compareTo(actNode.getValue()) < 0) {
            if (actNode.getLeft() == null) {
                posFound = true;
                actNode.setLeft(new Node(value));
                //checkAVL(actNode);
            } else
                actNode = actNode.getLeft();
        } else {
            if (actNode.getRight() == null) {
                posFound = true;
                actNode.setRight(new Node(value));
                //checkAVL(actNode);
            } else
                actNode = actNode.getRight();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the implementation of your binary tree. Perhaps addValue doesn't work correctly.

Comment: You also need to show the code for `Node`, I can see why you are getting upto `12` before the negative value. The negative value that you see could be a bug in your implementation of binary tree.

Comment: First of all please change the variable name which is same as method name. (contains).

Comment: A binary tree is a ordered tree, So why are you searching both the left and right node in `contains()`

Comment: @Debu binary tree doesn't have to be ordered, it only means that each node has at most two children.

Comment: did some changes. Edited the code so it shows my other approach where I search in an ordered tree. The Output still is endless though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you contain logic is seems wrong you should put null check in end logic also.And for binary search you have to target left side if value is less and right side if value is greater

```
// Base Cases: root is null or key is present at root
    if (root==null || root.key==key)
        return root;

    // val is greater than root's key
    if (root.key > key)
        return search(root.left, key);

    // val is less than root's key
    return search(root.right, key);
```

Iterative from my own implementation

```
public boolean search(V value) {
        TreeNode<V> localRoot = root;
        TreeNode<V> node = search(localRoot, value);
        if (node != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private TreeNode<V> search(TreeNode<V> root, V value) {
        int cmp;
        while (root != null) {
            cmp = getCompareValue(value, root.getValue());
            if (cmp == 0) {
                return root;
            } else if (cmp < 0) {
                root = root.getLeftChield();
            } else {
                root = root.getRightChield();
            }
        }

        return null;

    }
```

Comment: you're right, my logic seems wrong. I will add my previous approach which is similar to yours but produces the same Output

Comment: problem is still the same though, the Output continues even though it found the Node :/

Comment: please return Node from your method and check for null.Boolean seems too complicated.